# Using CustomFormat involving IfThen

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

I have a delphi multi-device form with a listview linked via livebindings to a TFDMEMtable. I display 4 fields from that table in the listview. The 3rd of which is a date which can legitimately be null. I am trying to use a CustomFormat on the corresponding LinkListControlToField entry to format the datetime as desired and to handle null dates. I am setting it in the IDE, not assigning it. This is the basic model I am working with:

```
IfThen(Self.Owner.UpdateDate.IsNull,%s,FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn',StrToDateTime(%0:s)))
```

I could equally test whether the string %s is empty - same difference. The above works OK until it strikes the first record where the date is null (and %s is therefore empty). It stops displaying listview data after that. I have tried all manner of trickery for specifying the "true" value e.g. '', "", ToStr(%s) etc etc.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: `%s` is not a string. `‘%s‘` is.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally got it. Instead of converting %s into a date, if I used the field directly it worked. e.g.

```
IfThen(Self.Owner.UpdateDate.IsNull,%s,FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn',Self.Owner.UpdateDate.AsDateTime))
```

Or, alternatively:

```
IfThen(%s="",%0:s,FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn',Self.Owner.UpdateDate.AsDateTime))
```

For those interested in actually getting assistance, please ignore the downvotes - they are simply WRONG. Both of the solutions above WORK (Delphi 10.2.3). Please see my comment below for more detail.

Comment: Sorry, Delphi should complain that both of those examples contain syntax errors, `%s` in the first case and both `%s = ""` and `%0:s` in the second.

Comment: Delphi doesn‘t use double quotes for strings. `''` is the empty string (two single quotes).

Comment: Normally delphi does not use double quotes, but they are acceptable in this case - it works - and there are plenty of examples out there where double quotes are used in this specific context.
If I replace the %0:s with just %s, it does not work. The second use of %s requires that index.
I think the 2 downvotes are unwarranted and harsh.